# Convert String "2011-06-27T14:03:19.5300000+07:00" To Datetime

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have result string date xml export from database like "2011-06-27T14:03:19.5300000+07:00". How to Convert to format datetime fully(date and time) in C# or VB.Net language datetime?

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

> The DateTime.Parse(String) method
>   tries to convert the string
>   representation of a date and time
>   value to its DateTime equivalent. The
>   string to be parsed can take any of
>   the following forms:
>
> - A string with a date and a time
>     component.
> - A string with a date but no time
>     component.
> - A string with a time but no date
>     component.
>
> A string that includes time zone
>   information and conforms to ISO 8601.
>   For example, the first of the
>   following two strings designates the
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC); the
>   second designates the time in a time
>   zone seven hours earlier than UTC:
>
> - 2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000Z
> - **2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000-07:00**
>
> A string that includes the GMT
>   designator and conforms to the RFC
>   1123 time format. For example:
>
> - Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT
>
> A string that includes the date and
>   time along with time zone offset
>   information. For example:
>
> - 03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2011-06-27T14:03:19.5300000+07:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

The main point is to use **`DateTime.TryParse`**

```
string rawDate = "2011-06-27T14:03:19.5300000+07:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(rawDate, out dt))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to parse");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `XDocument` you can simply call [conversion operator to `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343203.aspx).